# SAS proc report ensure that sections do not split between pages

Tags: sas, rtf, proc-report

I'm creating rtf report and group data by Var that is not into final report. I also added the split line between groups

```
 column var stat group1 group2 group3;
  define var/'' group noprint;
  define stat/display "Statistic" ;
  define group1/display "Group 1" ;
  define group2/display "Group 2" ;
  define group3/display "Group 3" ;
  
   compute after var;
    line '';
   endcomp;
```

How to ensure that a Var group does not break between pages?

If there is no room for whole group, the whole group should be moved to the next page

Comment: It seems like this *should* be possible, but I don't see a quick solution.  Maybe try ODS WORD and see if it does any better?  It does have a KEEP_LINES option and a KEEP_NEXT,  but it's not clear if you can apply them to a group.  https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2022/06/10/ods-destinations-microsoft-word/.  Only other thought is to do it manually, like https://www.pharmasug.org/proceedings/2020/QT/PharmaSUG-2020-QT-349.pdf, or post-process the RTF file to add /KEEP tags where you want them. Honestly, I would call tech support and ask about adding it to ODS WORD, if it's not there already.